# How to search using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ruby-on-rails-4, filter

I'm using the following code for now:

```
def self.search(query)
    where("name like ?", "%#{query}%") 
end
```

which works only for name, but basically I need it to work for everything (date of birth, surname, name + surname and so on). Can you please pass me some ideas how I could make this piece of code more suitable for my needs?

Thank you.

Comment: check out https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search

Comment: This should work `where("name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ? OR dob LIKE ?", "%#{query}%","%#{query}%","%#{query}%")`

Comment: i think on `dob` this wont work if `dob` `datetime` column type.

Comment: @Pavan tried that and it doesn't work. Finds only either by name or by surname, but not if I want to find using both of those parameters.

Comment: If want search by combination of both replace `OR` with `AND`.And also it doesn't work for `date_of_birth` if it `datetime datatype`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, then the [`dusen`](https://github.com/makandra/dusen) gem will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, add:

```
def self.search(cols, query)
  tbl = self.arel_table
  fq = tbl[cols.shift].matches("%#{query}%")
  q = cols.inject(fq) do |acc, col|
    acc.or(tbl[col].matches("%#{query}%"))
  end
  where(q)
end
```

And then you can use it like:

```
User.search([:name, :surname], 'name')
```

Which will generate nice SQL like:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (("users"."name" LIKE '%name%'
OR "users"."surname" LIKE '%name%'))
```

If you need finer control over your query, I sometimes add the following convenience method to AR:

```
def self.arel_where(&block); where(yield self.arel_table); end
```

And then you could do:

```
User.arel_where do |tbl|
  name = '%name%'; surname = '%sur%'
  tbl[:name].matches(name).and(tbl[:surname].matches(surname))
end
```